# Маска для блока (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

Доброе утро!

Как сделать такую маску для блока?

Постоянно накладывать и обрабатывать картинки в фотошопе и подстраивать размеры не хочется совсем)

Заранее благодарен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используй SVG mask for SVG elements [сравнение поддержки способов маскирования](https://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdb) и описание –
http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вырезаете "волну" в отдельный PNG и накладываете его поверх блоков. Например, вот так:

```css
.block {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}

.block.block-1 {
  background:#000 url(http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/budapest-hungary.jpg) no-repeat center;
}

.block.block-2 {
  background:#000 url(http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/matthias-church-budapest.jpg) no-repeat center;
}

.block.block-3 {
  background:#000 url(http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/frankfurt-evening.jpg) no-repeat center;
}

.block-text {
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:40px 0;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.block-wave {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFyWp.png) repeat-x center top;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-1">
  <div class="block-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div class="block-wave"></div>
</div>

<div class="block block-2">
  <div class="block-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div class="block-wave"></div>
</div>

<div class="block block-3">
  <div class="block-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div class="block-wave"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, в моём случае не подойдет :c
(либо я криворукий)

Comment: @user234223 с чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том что если я возьму другую картинку, то произойдет следующее: http://imgur.com/a/eQzaC

Comment: С этой картинкой все хорошо только потому что она обрезана...

Comment: @user234223 по скриншоту не особо понятно. Уточню, что PNG должен быть с прозрачным фоном. И в CSS нужно указывать `background: url(url_картинки) repeat-x center top;`, и высота блока должна быть равна высоте картинки. Если же у вас не получается вырезать волну, потому что она сделана не отдельным слоем/слоями, то это однозначно вина дизайнера. Требуйте от него исправить это дело

Comment: Да, действительно. Там вообще слой кривой...
Ещё один момент, не подскажите как сделать такую штуку? - По тому же принципу? http://imgur.com/a/Poyel

Comment: @user234223 да, можно по тому же принципу - поулчится наиболее кроссбраузерный вариант

Comment: Почему не SVG? 

Comment: Я, вроде, уже ответил. Слой волнистый поверх изображений. В чем проблема сначала нарисовать div с картинкой, затем div с волной? Волна - png, ARGB

Answer (score 1):

Слой тот, что снизу (волнистый, белый) накладывай *поверх* необходимых изображений.

Comment: Пример можно? - Не совсем понятно, но кажется костыль.